# How to instruct CMAKE to use Intel MKL in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, intel-mkl

I am trying to create a `CMAKE` to build a `Visual Studio 2017 x64` solution in which I use a few `Intel MKL` functions to calculate the inverse of a general matrix using `LU decomposition`. I get the following errors when I build the project:

```
Error   LNK2005 mkl_serv_allocate already defined in mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib(mkl_intel_thread.dll) test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj)  
Error   LNK2005 mkl_serv_malloc already defined in mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib(mkl_intel_thread.dll)   test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj)  
Error   LNK2005 mkl_serv_deallocate already defined in mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib(mkl_intel_thread.dll)   test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj)  
Error   LNK2005 mkl_serv_free already defined in mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib(mkl_intel_thread.dll) test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj)  
Error   LNK2005 mkl_serv_format_print already defined in mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib(mkl_intel_thread.dll) test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\mkl_core.lib(mkl_msg_support.obj) 
Error   LNK2005 mkl_serv_inspector_suppress already defined in mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib(mkl_intel_thread.dll)   test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\mkl_core.lib(mkl_semaphore.obj)   
Error   LNK2005 mkl_serv_inspector_unsuppress already defined in mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib(mkl_intel_thread.dll) test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\mkl_core.lib(mkl_semaphore.obj)   
Error   LNK2005 mkl_serv_thread_yield already defined in mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib(mkl_intel_thread.dll) test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\mkl_core.lib(mkl_semaphore.obj)   
Error   LNK2005 mkl_serv_unlock already defined in mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib(mkl_intel_thread.dll)   test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\mkl_core.lib(mkl_semaphore.obj)   


Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __kmpc_global_thread_num referenced in function mkl_lapack_dgetrf    test    C:\Users\test\build\mkl_intel_thread.lib(dgetrf_par.obj)    
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __kmpc_global_thread_num test    C:\Users\test\build\mkl_intel_thread.lib(d__scal_drv.obj)   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __kmpc_ok_to_fork referenced in function mkl_lapack_dgetrf   test    C:\Users\test\build\mkl_intel_thread.lib(dgetrf_par.obj)    
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __kmpc_ok_to_fork    test    C:\Users\test\build\mkl_intel_thread.lib(d__scal_drv.obj)   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __kmpc_push_num_threads referenced in function mkl_lapack_dgetrf test    C:\Users\test\build\mkl_intel_thread.lib(dgetrf_par.obj)    
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __kmpc_push_num_threads  test    C:\Users\test\build\mkl_intel_thread.lib(d__scal_drv.obj)   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __kmpc_fork_call referenced in function mkl_lapack_dgetrf    test    C:\Users\test\build\mkl_intel_thread.lib(dgetrf_par.obj)    
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __kmpc_fork_call test    C:\Users\test\build\mkl_intel_thread.lib(d__scal_drv.obj)   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __kmpc_serialized_parallel referenced in function mkl_lapack_dgetrf  test    C:\Users\test\build\mkl_intel_thread.lib(dgetrf_par.obj)    
Error   LNK1120 16 unresolved externals test    C:\Users\user1\test\build\Debug\test.exe
```

Is this due to the following CMAKE?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

PROJECT(MYPROJECT)

set(MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries/windows/mkl/include")
set(MKL_LIBRARIES "C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries/windows/mkl/lib/intel64")

include_directories(${MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(test MACOSX_BUNDLE)

target_link_libraries(
            test
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_blas95_ilp64.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_blas95_lp64.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_core.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_core_dll.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_intel_ilp64.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_intel_ilp64_dll.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_intel_lp64.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_intel_thread.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_lapack95_ilp64.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_lapack95_lp64.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_rt.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_sequential.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_sequential_dll.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_tbb_thread.lib"
            ${MKL_LIBRARIES}/mkl_tbb_thread_dll.lib"
```

I have the `bin` folder containing the `DLL`s in the system `PATH`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\windows\redist\intel64_win\mkl
```

Comment: How about adding the detailed error messages to your question. Hard to help unless we know what the unresolved symbols are.

Comment: I don't know the answer but it's clear you have the wrong list of libraries. You've included some that you shouldn't have, that's why you have 'already defined' error messages, and missed out some that you needed, that's why you have 'unresolved' error messages. A good look at the MKL documentation is needed I think.

Comment: You are linking 4 variants of the same library. Only link either static or dynamic and either ilp64 or lp64 depending on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

You link something unnecessary. You can solve this error by setting the link flag.

```
LINK_FLAGS "/force:multiple"
```

and you lost something neccessary, please link `libiomp***.dll`. [You can refer to this post](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/Linking-errors-with-mkl-intel-thread/td-p/894194)